# Get from prime number theorem to the approximate equality of nth prime to n*logn

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I saw in my textbook the following theorem:
$\pi(n)\sim n⁄ \log n$

And it states the following corollary from this theorem:
$p_n\sim n \log n$

I tried to think how they made that conclusion but to no avail.
Can someone explain me, considering I've just started my first degree in CS?

Answer (score 3):

The function $p_n$ is the inverse of the function $\pi$

And if we calculate $p_n(\pi(n))$ with the given approximations, we have
$p_n(\pi(n))\approx \frac{n}{log(n)}\log(\frac{n}{log(n)})= \frac{n}{log(n)}(log(n)-log(log(n))\approx\frac{n}{log(n)}log(n)=n$

Comment: This is not a way to get $p_n$, but a justification that the formula is asymptotically right.

Comment: I don't understand why $p_n$ is a function rather than just the nth prime number?

Comment: We can consider it to be a function which maps $n$ to the $n-th$ prime. And $\pi(n)$ determines $m$ with $p(m)=n$